# Mass edit a field in Odoo

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-8

I want to select some of the items like in the photo, and then have a button behind "delete" button to validate all the selected fields at the same time. How can I do this without adding modules?

[image]

```
class AccountVoucher(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.voucher'

    validated = fields.Boolean('Validated')
```

Comment: Odoo 8 man :-O you could create a server action with python code (no module added!) and just write "validated=True" to the records. Or if you need both ways (validating and "un"validating) just toggle the value in your action python code. Server actions can be added to the "More" menu, which is already showing in your screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a function into account.voucher model to change the value of a field and call it from server action. You can refer below code to create **server action** in odoo-8.

```
<record id="ir_actions_server_validate" model="ir.actions.server">
        <field name="sequence" eval="5"/>
        <field name="state">code</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.server</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="model_account_voucher"/>
        <field name="code">action = pool.get('account.voucher').action_validate(cr, uid, None, context)</field>
        <field name="condition">True</field>
        <field name="name">Validate</field>
    </record>
```